# How do I get Eclipse to recognize R and the resources in Android's Lunar Lander?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create the Lunar Lander example for Android in Eclipse, but some of the code is not compiling.  Anywhere in the code that references "R." is giving me errors.  At first it was saying that R was not recognized or declared, so I imported it from Android via the quick fix menu.  But now the resources that are referenced after the R are not being recognized.

How can I fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: what is the import that you have used for R?

Comment: Haven't used it for an import, at least knowlingly.  I created a new Android project and copied all the source and resource files and folders from the Lunar Lander sample.  R was being used in the sample's code without a declaration in that code (probably supposed to be in one of the imported packages).

Comment: No R is not supposed to be imported it is directly referenced if you have used correct package name. At this point check whether your R file is generated or not and if yes then the package of the R and your source code is same or not?

Comment: I've added the line import android.R; to each of the source code files.  But that just makes it where, in the phrase "R.string.menu_start", for instance, R is no longer giving me an error, but menu_start suddenly is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think u import android.R
U have to import com.example.android.lunarlander.R

Comment: There isn't an R file in com.example.android.lunarlander.  Is there supposed to be?

Comment: It looks like there's supposed to be one in automatically-generated Java files, but there are no such files...period.  I'm guessing if I fix that, the R file would be taken care of as well.  How would I do that?

Comment: @Panzercrisi if the R.java file is not present, the most common cause is an error in an xml file so that R.java cannot be generated. Eclipse will sometimes insert import android.R. This is a bug. Remove the import and close the file to save the changes.

Comment: I noticed the Build Automatically option under Project was unchecked, and so I checked it.  Mysteriously that got the R file to be created and put into the previously empty gen folder.  Thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

try to use getResource() to reference R

Comment: This solved my problem. As soon as i put the "getResource()" method, the R.java file was generated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem all the time, the problem for me was that there was a file in my hdpi resources which was (`res\drawable-hdpi\image.xcf`) not a jpg. it was a xcf. and deleting this solved the issue.